# Displaying a html link with JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am trying to display a html link and load it via json but I can't seem to get this to work I have tried in the below but it is displaying as text and not a link.

```
    "test" : {

"description": "A little test '<a href=\"https://www.google.com\">Visit Google<\/a>'"

            }
```

I have also tried removing the \ from the end of the `a` tag but this doesn't seem to work.

Loading method:

```
function() {
        angular.module("testerMod").provider("language", function() {
            "ngInject";
            this.path = "/assets/locale/", this.userLanguage = "en", this.$get = function(e) {
                return ["$http", "$state", "$log", "$cookies", function(t, n, i, o) {
                    return function(a, s) {
                        var r, l, c;
                        return l = _.find(s.locales, {
                            code: a
                        }), null == l ? (r = _.find(s.locales, {
                            code: o["language"]
                        }), null != r ? a = r.code : (c = _.find(s.locales, {
                            code: e.userLanguage
                        }), a = null != c ? c.code : _.find(s.locales, {
                            "default": !0
                        }).code), void n.go("home", {
                            language: a
                        })) : t({
                            method: "GET",
                            url: e.path + a + ".json"
                        }).then(function(e) {
                            return e.data
                        }, function(e) {
                            return i.error("Language Load Error")
                        })
                    }
                }]
            }(this)
        })
    }
```

using library three js

Comment: You'll need to show what is consuming/using this JSON or we can't take a guess why this doesn't work... JSON by itself is data, not code.

Comment: Do you mean how I'm loading it or which library is using the data?

Comment: Either or both - JSON without code is just text, so until we see what code is involved, it's impossible to guess what might be happening.

Comment: loading method added and library used, the text loads perfectly though not the link that also comes as text but with the a tags missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe it is a good idea to separate view and data i have extracted properties: link source, link text this way Json would only mean to transfer data and browser or app you are using will render the view according to your apps logic.

```
{
  "test":{ 
  "description": "A little test ",
  "link_source":"https://www.google.com",
  "link_text":"Visit Google"
   }
}
```

for your version to work you may check validity of your json here if you wish https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/
also there is another article here about Json serialization http://www.popoloproject.com/appendices/json-patterns.html